# get checkins or venue_history of a user from foursquare

Tags: ruby, rubygems, foursquare

Does anybody has any idea about how to get a venue history of a user from foursquare? I am using foursquare2 gem and I can connect to foursquare. I want to send a user's email address to foursquare and get the venue history of the user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't get the checkin history of a user without them [authorising your app](https://developer.foursquare.com/overview/auth). What you are suggesting (using someone's email address to get their venue history) isn't possible.

Comment: yes Martin I read about it yesterday. Foursquare not supply it for now :/

Answer (score 1):

As Martin said, you'll need the user to authorize your application to access their check-in history. Once they've authorized your app, you can call the [users/checkins](https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/users/checkins.html) endpoint to access their check-in history, or [users/venuehistory](https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/users/venuehistory.html) to access their venue history.